# PHP: How to split strings with zero or more delimiters?

Tags: php, preg-split

My input:

```
A B C D
E
F G H
```

My code:

```
$field=preg_split("/ /",$line);
```

After that, the value of `$field[0]` for line 1 and 3 matches correctly, while for line 2 it contains a mysterious whitespace and `$field[0]` failed to match with "E" downstream. What's wrong here and how to fix it?

(EDIT: Problem Solved, thanks @Toto)

Comment: What if you use `explode` instead of `preg_split` ?

Comment: Works fine for me. Don't you have unprintable character before `E`?

Comment: Ditto, works for me. Are you reading these lines from a file?

Comment: Give us a real life example of the data you are using. I bet that `A B C D....` is not the real data

Comment: @Toto
Yes, you're right!
A close check with the original data with original encoding shows that there's some non-English unprintable character!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put my comment as an answer as it seems to solve OP's problem.

Your split by space works for me.
I guess you have some unprintable character at the begining of the string.